# Openlayers 3 security issue

Tags: javascript, security, mapbox, openlayers-3

I have an issue with Openlayers 3.
When I want to load mapbox tiles like this :

```
source:new ol.source.TileJson({
url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.world-dark.jsonp'
})
```

I have this message :

SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try using `https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.world-dark.jsonp`

Comment: It doesn't work. I have the same message :(

Comment: Could you create a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to make it easier to investigate?

Answer (score 2):

Set the [crossOrigin option](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/apidoc/ol.source.TileJSON.html) to make the request be sent with CORS headers.

Comment: source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
    url: 'url.jsonp',
    crossOrigin:'null'
    })